# How to open make hyperlink for txt files

Tags: php, html, file, fopen, txt

I created 3 text files and I want to create a bullet form list with hyperlinks that will direct the user to each file created. How can I code this?

```
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li>" . <a fopen("test.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");>Test 1</a>  "</li>";
echo "<li>"  . $filename = 'test2.txt' . "</li>";
echo "/<ul>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `/<ul>` is not the correct closing tag, it should be `</ul>`

On the other hand, you may use the Nowdoc string quoting syntax (or similar):

```
<?php
echo <<<'EOD'

<ul>
<li><a href='test.txt'>Test1</a></li>
<li><a href='test2.txt'>Test2</a></li>
</ul>

EOD;

?>
```

For further reference on the above , please view the official documentation:

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc